# how to create never growing data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, binance-api-client

how to create never growing data dataframe which append a new row at last and delete first row of data frame everytime.
I want to create binance live kline historical data steaming to the now and append the latest kline ticker data.
It may light for consume less data storage.
I thankful for answering.

Comment: There is no automatic way.  You just need to delete the first row when you add the final row.